# How should i add this arrow beside about?

Tags: html, css

```
a.arrow::after {
    display:block;
    content: "";
    width: 63px;
    height: 59px;
    background-image: url(../../img/arrow.png);
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

How to put arrow beside about us?

[aroow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar81P.png)

[navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRc2t.jpg)

Comment: Does the arrow do anything, or is it just decoration? Please edit your question to include your markup (a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) would be preferable.)

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in an unordered list, no need to set width and height, just set padding if you want them to behave the same and line up; If you want to use a pseudo then I'd recommend using line-height if you know they will never line-break.

Try something like this and adapt to suit:

```css
.inline-list {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.inline-list li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 1em 2em;
background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<ul class="inline-list">
<li>About Us</li>
<li>></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:
You can set the position of arrow according to your need.

```css
.sp{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
.p li{
 list-style-type: none;
}
.p{
 display: flex;
 width: 70%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.icon_p{
 position: relative;
}

.icon:after{
 content: '▼';
 position: absolute;
 left: 65px;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sp">
    <div class="p">
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="icon_p"><a href="#" class="icon">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GetInTouch</a></li>
    </div>
</div>
```